# Route back home without a hash in the url... backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, hash

I am not really talking about `PushState` I don't think. I am saving a new model into my localStorage collection. There is an action on the home page that routes to a new view which has a form that serializes the fields and creates an object that adds into localStorage with the `create` function.

I commented out `router.navigate` below in the code for testing purposes, to see if my view would render properly by manually removing the hash (#) after the event triggers (it does).

The `router.navigate` does route back home successfully, though leaving a trailing hash (#). I think the hash is causing a problem, is there a way to route back without the hash. Or do I need to rethink some code if the hash is not allowing me to re-render?

```
save: function(e) {
    var playerObject = $(e.currentTarget).serializeObject();
    var playersCollection = new PlayersCollection();
    playersCollection.fetch({
        success: function(player) {
            player.create(playerObject);
            //router.navigate('', {trigger: true});
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking the [source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-179), you'll see that `navigate` calls a function `_updateHash`.  It always adds the leading "#":

```
_updateHash: function(location, fragment, replace) {
  if (replace) {
    var href = location.href.replace(/(javascript:|#).*$/, '');
    location.replace(href + '#' + fragment);
  } else {
    location.hash = '#' + fragment;
  }
}
```

So I don't see a "kosher" way to do it.  I suppose you could modify your Backbone.js source (exclude the hash when the fragment is empty, or add an option to `navigate` that excludes it).

Comment: Oh okay thanks, Ill try and muster up all the brain power I have left to figure out if there is anything I can do to get it to render properly with the new model, working with the hash. Id rather avoid editing the source, I mean it's not like I am so far in that I couldn't modify a few things to get it working properly.